# Postgres - dumping from one table into a different-named table

Tags: postgresql, export

I want to export data from one database table (using pg_dump) and then import it to a different-named table on a different database.

For small files I know I can manually edit the dump file and change the table name in the COPY command.

Unfortunately several of my tables produce dump files that are beyond the capabilities of any of my editors, so this option isn't available

Any suggestions?

Comment: use perl, sed or awk to do a search and replace on the file:
perl -pe "s/searchString/replaceString/g" data.txt